# Maxwell's equation along a curve and Evolution of the polarization vector

Tags: electromagnetism, geometric-optics, polarization, fiber-optics

So here is the setup: There is a coiled cylindrical wire. At each point on its axis, we define a tangent direction $\hat{t}(s)$, and a normal $\hat{n}(s)$ and binormal $\hat{b}(s)$, $s$ is a parametrization of the trajectory, and $\rho$ is the perpendicular distance from the fiber axis. We define an electric field propagating through this waveguide as

$\vec{E}$($\rho$,$s$) = $exp(i \beta s) f(\rho) [c_1(s) \hat{n}(s) + c_2(s) \hat{b}(s)]$,

where $\beta$ and $f(\rho)$ are, respectively, the propagation constant and modal amplitude appropriate to the straight fibre. I want to obtain the evolution equation of $c_1(s)$ and $c_2(s)$ in terms of the torsion and curvature of the fiber (which should come after using Frenet-Serret equations, I believe); after applying Maxwell's equation (probably the condition $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$). But I am struggling with performing the curl operation as the basis vectors are changing along the path.

My question stems from a result that Sir M.V. Berry derived in one of his papers https://michaelberryphysics.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/berry159.pdf ("Interpreting the Anholonomy of coiled fiber"). Here, the question that I have asked is basically deriving equation 2 of this paper.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is a bit too broad at the moment.

To work with Maxwell's equations you need to define a coordinate system, not a just basis at some point. Granted you defined basis along a curve, but that still leaves nearly all of the space. What is the basis 1m outside the wire? You either need to remove that space by defining boundary conditions, which, I think, you don't want to do (I assume you want scattering boundaries at infinity or PEC boundaries far away), or you need to define coordinates and basis at all points of interest.

I would suggest to define the region you are solving in as an infinitely long twisting tube with PEC boundaries. The radius of the tube is finite. Inside the tube there is a lot of empty space, and right at the centre there is your wire. The coiling is loose enough for the big tube not to cut into itself. The radius of the big tube is large enough for influence of PEC boundaries to be acceptable for your task at hand. Now define coordinate system inside the tube, which, I presume will be some transformation of cyllindrical coordinates.Once you have the coordinates you can work out the expressions for curl, div and grad. Then you can compose the equations and only then can you aim to solve them. At different points of the journey you may want to take limits of very loose twisting in order to simplify equations